# iPhone- Spritekit Programming: Loading Scene from Button

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

I am new to the spritekit system. However, I have some questions. I have an app that has a menu screen, instructions page, etc..., none of which recquire me loading a skcene. However, I want to be able to load my "Game" scene on the press of a button. How would I do that regarding code?

FIXED:

I just did not check the IB settings for one of my views: my view type should be SKView.

Comment: Create a default Game Project in Xcode and look at the View Controller.

Comment: what exactly is the issue - the presenting a scene part or the button running some code part?

Comment: presenting the scene @LearnCocos2D

Comment: and what specifically? There's presentScene on the view so: [self.view presentScene:[YourScene node]]

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Ya but for some reaason there is a problem. I have a normal viewcontroller based app. No spritekit stuff there. But I want to implement a spritekit scene for just one of the viewcontrollers that I load by clicking a button. Everything works but when I try to present the scene on the viewController, it crashes.

Comment: then give us the details of this crash, where it occurs and what it says in the log

Comment: @LearnCocos2D the crash occurs when I push the button and I get an NSException something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create new SKView in your view controller's -viewDidLoad: method

  ```
  SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
  ```
- Then create new SKScene class in a separate file

  ```
  @interface GameScene : SKScene

  @end
  ```
- Return to your previous view controller and place this code in your
  button's event handler

  ```
  GameScene* scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(768,1024)];
  SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
  [spriteView presentScene: scene];
  ```

More info in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW3).